# lscpu and cpuid say I have AVX2, but vpsllvw does not work

Tags: assembly, x86-64, avx2, cpuid

If I run `lscpu` or look in `/proc/cpuinfo`, they both say that my processor supports AVX2.

```
$ lscpu | grep -o avx2
avx2
```

However, when I used `vpsllvw` in my code, it gave SIGILL.

```
bits 64
global main
section .text
main:
        movdqa xmm0, [initial]
        vpsllvw xmm0, [shift]
        ret


section .data
        align 16
        initial dw 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
        shift dw 4,0,4,0,4,0,4,0
```

Assembled with `$ nasm -g -felf64 test.asm && g++ -g -m64 test.o`

I know this isn't a lot of information to work with, but it's all I can think of.

Processor is Intel Core i5-7200U

### Solution

Turns out that only the dword and qword versions are in AVX2, `vpsllvw` is AVX512.

Comment: What OS / version?  Are you running Linux in a VM?  Did you change the VM settings between restarts, or something, so Linux booted with AVX2 available, but now it's running in a machine that doesn't report AVX2 via CPUID?  (IDK why `vpsllw ymm0, ymm1, 1` or something would fault, though; if the kernel has AVX2 in `/proc/cpuinfo`, it would have set the control register bits that allow AVX instructions to run without faulting.)

Comment: Running debian 10 natively
`$ uname -a` give `Linux GLaDOS2 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 2020-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
`

Comment: Also, `0x29c67af & (1<<5)` is non-zero, so `CPUID` *is* reporting AVX2 availability (https://sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm), contrary to your question title.  What `vpsllw` instruction did you try to run, exactly ([mcve])?  Did you accidentally use it in a way that required AVX512?  e.g. `vpsllw ymm0, [rdi], 1`?  AVX2 only allows the source to be a register, for the immediate form, or to take the count from memory, not the data to be shifted.  But AVX-512 does allow memory.

Comment: Now that you say it, I guess A is not actually `1100`... And yeah I'm using vpsllw xmm0, [asdf], so that's probably it

Comment: I tried changing it to `movdqa xmm1,[asdf]; vpsllw xmm0,xmm1` and it still says it's an illegal instruction...

Comment: Oh wait a minute, you're not using the `xmm, [mem], immediate` form, you're using the `xmm, xmm, [mem]` form, with the *count* coming from memory, using NASM's shorthand that lets you omit the first source if it's the same as the destination.  Yeah that's fine with AVX1.  You still haven't included a [mcve] of the code that faults in your question.

Comment: Please also provide a disassembly of the binary.  If the opcode starts with `62`, it's AVX-512.  AVX and AVX2 opcodes start with `c4` or `c5` (rule of thumb; there are exceptions).

Comment: Well the code you show should work.  This is rather strange.

Comment: Do other VEX-encoded instructions work, like `vmovdqa xmm0, [asdf]`?  (Which you should be using for performance reasons instead of legacy-SSE `movdqa`, at least if you ever use any 256-bit instructions.  Mixing 128-bit AVX and SSE is fine as long as the CPU is not already in a "dirty-uppers" state.)

Comment: This is extremely strange.  I have two possible explanations: (a) you are for some reason assembling for 32 bit mode while building a 64 bit program or vice versa and thus the instructions are encoded incorrectly or (b) the OS has not enabled AVX2 for some reason.  (a) can be resolved if you show us a [mcve], as for (b), well, no idea.

Comment: So let it be known that I did a big dumb: I've been saying vpsllw, which works fine, vpsll**v**w is the problem. Also it does appear to be encoded using `62` (not exactly sure how to include that, I just grabbed that from gdb using `x (the address)`)

Comment: @Rubixninja314 Use `objdump -d` to disassemble the object file.  Anyway, that would settle it.

Comment: But `vpsllvw` is unambiguously AVX512, no?  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpsllvw:vpsllvd:vpsllvq

Comment: Oh my goodness, I was looking right at the [documentation](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VPSLLVW_VPSLLVD_VPSLLVQ.html), I didn't even notice that only the dword and qword versions were available on AVX2

Comment: @Rubixninja314 There you go!  To prevent this in the future, I believe there's some way to tell nasm to restrict the available instructions for you.  Might have been the `cpu` directive.

Comment: @nate-eldredge Thank you! ....now how do I mark it solved? I've been trying for minutes...

Comment: Use the "Answer your own question" button to write a brief answer.  [After two days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277960/why-cant-you-accept-your-own-answer-immediately) you'll be able to click the check mark to indicate that question is resolved.  Alternatively, since the problem was the result of a typo, you can flag it to be closed on that basis (under "needs improvement : community-specific reason").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`vpsllVw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpsllvw:vpsllvd:vpsllvq) requires AVX512.  **AVX2 only has dword / qword per-element-variable-count shifts.**  (And only dword for arithmetic right shift.  `vpsravq` also requires AVX512.)  Rotates also require AVX-512: `vprord` / `vprorvd` and so on.

The initial version of this question was about [`vpsllw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psllw:pslld:psllq), the AVX form of the instruction that dates back to MMX/SSE2 (using the same count for all elements, from the bottom of the register or memory location, or as an immediate).  That's what the part below is about.

---

**For future readers with other vpsllw / vpslld / vpsllq problems** (or VPSLLDQ shuffles), perhaps you used a form of `vpsllw` (with an immediate count and memory source data) that requires AVX-512VL, which your CPU doesn't have.

- AVX1/2 (VEX prefix) allows `vpsllw  xmm1, xmm2, imm8` (with AVX2 allowing ymm)
- AVX512 (EVEX prefix) allows `vpsllw  xmm1, xmm2/mem, imm8`, with the data to be shifted coming from memory. Also the ymm/zmm forms, of course.
- AVX1/2 and AVX512 allow `vpsllw  xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/mem128` (count from the low 64 bits of the memory operand).

So `vpsllw xmm1, [rdi], 1` could only be encoded with an EVEX prefix, and by default NASM won't stop or warn you about that.

(If you want to stop yourself from accidentally using CPU features, YASM can do that with a `CPU skylake AMD` directive (AMD to include x86-64 stuff; it's not a very well-engineered system).  But YASM doesn't support AVX-512 at all last I checked, so this is only going to work for stuff before that, not for various levels of AVX-512.  I think there's also some support for doing this with NASM, perhaps with a macro package.  GAS can do CPU feature checking with a command line option.)

---

**I don't know why Intel chose *not* to allow a load-and-shift memory source for the AVX1/2 immediate-count forms**.  The restriction appears to be entirely arbitrary, and there's no machine-code encoding reason why it would be a problem.  It uses the `r/m` field in ModRM to encode the read-only source operand ([the "D" row on the operand-encoding table for that instruction's manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psllw:pslld:psllq#instruction-operand-encoding)), same as the EVEX form, so it seems like an arbitrary decision to make a memory source illegal instead of allowing it.  (With the `r` field being extra opcode bits, and the VEX VVVV field being the destination register.)

Probably some kind of historical reason while they were planning AVX before Sandybridge was designed?  Since legacy-SSE shifts couldn't ever shift memory, Nehalem CPU internals wouldn't have had to support having a memory source for that kind of uop.  Seems like a lame excuse, and probably didn't benefit them much since Sandybridge ended up redesigning the internal uop formats significantly anyway.

Instructions like `imul reg, [mem], imm` with a similar form exist, although that uses ModRM `/r` as the destination reg, not as extra opcode bits (which is how it's encodeable with VEX).  So perhaps there are no instructions that use `/r` as extra opcode bits, *and* use `ModRM:r/m` as a read-only source operand that can be memory?

Regular scalar shifts like `shl dword [rdi], 4` use `r/m` as a read-write operand (with `/r` being extra opcode bits), like many one-operand 8086 instructions such as `neg dword [rdi]`, so decoding a memory operand along with extra opcode bits from `/r` is something the decoders already have to handle.

Seems like poor design to introduce an arbitrary unexpected limitation, defeating the point of being CISC with a somewhat compact machine-code format that allows memory-source operands.  Fortunately they fixed that with AVX-512, but that leads to the possibility of accidentally using AVX-512 when you didn't intend or expect to.

Comment: I had half of this typed (or at least planned in my head) before the OP clarified that it *wasn't* the immediate form, and it's certainly a possible pothole for future readers so I wrote it up anyway.